# Rails 4: How to test Controller Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rails-console

How do I actually test this Controller Action, I wrote in my PurchasesController:

```
protect_from_forgery except: [:hook]
def hook
    params.permit! # Permit all Paypal input params
    status = params[:payment_status]
    if status == "Completed"
        @purchase = Purchase.find(params[:invoice])
        @purchase.update_attributes(status: status, transaction_id: params[:txn_id], purchased_at: Time.now)
        @purchase.save!
        @user = @tool.user
        @user.earned_money += @tool.price
        @user.save!
    end
    render nothing: true
end
```

preferably with my Rails Console?

Routes:

```
post "/purchases/:id" => "purchases#show"
post "/hook" => "purchases#hook"
```

Comment: you want to make the testing through console?

Comment: @Shabini Rajadas I thought I could pass the parameters to the path and check the database if that worked... But I did something wrong. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

You don't test controllers through the rails console.

Controllers in Rails respond to HTTP requests - they are instantiated by the routing component when it matches an incoming request. So you would test controllers by sending a HTTP request and inspecting the response.

You can manually test your controller by using the command line tool [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/) or the browser based Postman to send a request*. You can the use the rails console to check for side effects such as changes in the database.

However, you should consider using an automated testing tool such as [Minitest](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) or [RSpec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails) as manually testing your application is a flawed approach.

Comment: * - there are many tools to send HTTP requests. These are just two very popular examples.

Comment: You can instantiate a controller in the console but it would require you to setup a fake request and requires quite a bit of knowledge of how rails and rack work.  You can't just `pass the parameters to the path`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure you can test this through your console, unless you decouple/abstract the other operations being performed and then you test the units independently. With RSpec/Minitest, though you just have to create the records and do a post request to the `/hook` route, passing the expected params: `invoice`, `txn_id`, `payment_status`.

Let me know if that helps.